# ViewPager2: How to implement independent fragments

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-navigation, android-viewpager2

I know this is a broad question but it goes as follows. I have a Fragment that lists TODO tasks. Now I want to add a swipe view - a second page - that lists the already completed tasks. So basically what I want to achieve looks like this:

[Just imagine that there are two static pages "TODO" and "DONE"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydV9V.png)

This means that I need to share the data between the two screens. Also note that these two pages need to have a completely different layout.

I've done research and the brand new ViewPager2 seems to be the way to go.
**However,** the official documentation doesn't really talk about my use case. They seem to have pages that use the same layout and don't share data between themselves:
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view-2

Since ViewPager2 is *completely new* I decided to post a Stackoverflow question right away due to the simple fact that I am positive that my use case is the most popular one and thus, there will be more people with the same question.

Summa summarum: *How does one implement two Fragments - with independent layouts - that share data and are swipe views themselves by utilizing the new ViewPager2 library.*

Comment: use MVVM pattern and hold your data in ViewModel hosted inside your activity

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am using MVVM and the TODO-List is LiveData. I was wondering about the specific  viewpager2 implementation for two static fragments. I am also happy if you can provide me with more documentation.

Comment: @Pawel alright thank you I got ViewPager2 working. However, the ViewModel that I use has unintended behaviour. I therefore openend a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60129178/viewpager2-tabs-problem-with-viewmodel-state

Comment: @Pawel Ok I am now 100% sure that my current problem is not related to the Pages themselves.  Could you take a look ? Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60129178/viewpager2-tabs-problem-with-viewmodel-state